# using tolocaledatestring with 2-digi year returns wrong century

Tags: javascript, date

I'm manipulating some data coming from an external XML that I cannot change. This XML has dates in this format:

```
01-APR-39
```

and I want the date to become in this format:

```
01/04/1939
```

but using:

```
new Date('01-APR-39').toLocaleDateString('en-GB')
```

is returning wrong century:

```
01/04/2039
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: How is the parser supposed to know which century you want? See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this.

You need to decide the year cutoff

```js
const cutOff = 29; // or have a range
const getDateFromYY = dStr => {
  let [dd, mmm, yy] = dStr.split("-");
  const yyyy = +yy > cutOff ? "19" + yy : "20" + yy;
  return new Date(dd + "-" + mmm + "-" + yyyy).toLocaleDateString('en-GB')
};

console.log(getDateFromYY('01-APR-39'))

console.log(getDateFromYY('01-APR-19'))
```

Comment: Can you explain what the number `75` is? Why in case of `01-APR-76` the answer should be `01/04/2076`?

Comment: I updated to have a cutoff at 29 - so numbers > 29 will be 1900

Comment: Ok, I hope OP understands the idea of manual selection `cutOff`, otherwise in case `01-APR-19` he will receive `01/04/2019` :)